# Adding custom generic type template to CodeRush

Tags: visual-studio, coderush

I'm diving into creating my own coderush templates, and I use the auto-property templates heavily.  I'd like to add an IList property and auto-property.  I started by looking at the implementations of the List (pl.) and it's associated auto-prop (al.).  I also looked at the IEnumerable versions for reference.  I think I get the general syntax, but can't seem to find how to add IList to the available types that get rendered from ?Generic1Type?.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Nick

[Cross-posted on [CodeRush Forums](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/78273/267826.aspx#267826)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I might as well post an answer here as well.

It sounds like you are after the "Dynamic Lists" options page

---

Follow these steps to get to the Dynamic Lists options page:

1. From the DevExpress menu, select "Options...".
2. In the tree view on the left, navigate to this folder:

   Core
3. Select the "Dynamic Lists" options page.
   This page level is Advanced, and will only be visible if the Level combo on the lower-left of the Options dialog is set to Advanced or Expert.

---

Note that certain lists appear only when the correct language is selected in the dropdown box at the bottom of the screen. I think you'll need to Select "Neutral" in order to find the lists you are after.

From here you should be able to edit any of the Dynamic lists to your hearts content.

Comment: Interesting.  In Advanced/Expert mode, the only C# Type that's listed in Dynamic Lists is System.Single and doesn't let me add/replace.  At that, I notice when I select Expert, the highest icon the Options window shows me (upper right corner of dialog) is the blue Advanced icon.  Wonder if I have a fudded installation...

Comment: Ok, so the issue was just how I was "expecting" to use the dialog.  I changed the Language to Neutral and everything showed up.  The Add/Replace buttons don't become active until you enter something into the Mnemonic and Value textboxes.  Could be more intuitive, but whatever.  I added the il mnemonic and it worked.  Thanks!